# Git repository size increases on every Eclipse remote synchronization

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using Eclipse Remote synchronization to upload a PHP project from my Windows workstation to FreeBSD VM, where my web server is running. In order to make the synchronization Eclipse create on both machines .ptp-sync directory where stores the git objects.

Initially the project is ~1MB. But after every save (which triggers sync) this size increases to 2MB, 3MB, 5MB, 10MB etc, on both machines. After a couple of synchronizations it goes through hundreds of MB, to GBs. Once it reaches even 11GB. Of course the synchronization starts to take, instead 1-2 sec as it is initially, 1-2min. In such cases I should delete both .ptp-sync dirs and init Eclipse sync again.

I notice that the largest files are in .ptp-sync\objects\pack\

My last test, after 3 saves (and syncs) the repo increase steps were 77MB - 138MB - 267MB - 396MB. Just before that I try

```
git -C .ptp-sync --work-tree=. gc --prune
```

which reduces the size from 140MB to 77MB, but after 396MB it doesn't reduce anything. Next save make the repo 779MB.

One of my guesses was that it is not ignoring .ptp-sync which causes to push it everytime, although there is /.ptp-sync in .gitignore file, and also in Eclipse Preferences->Remote Development->Synchronized Projects->File Filtering.

P.S. Ah, and of course this does not happen on my colleague setup which is prity the same - he also uses Windows and Eclipse with a copy of the same VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out how to handle this situation. As I guess the .ptp-sync directory even it was added into .gitignore it wasn't actually ignored, and this cause its recommit on every repack.

The solution is to add into .ptp-sync/info/exclude the row `/.ptp-sync/`. Maybe the synchronization doesn't use .gitignore by default.

For different ways of ignoring files, the following link can give some info: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: Thank you for this! I noticed that the directory was growing rapidly & [Nvidia's fix is to delete the folder](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/sync-projects#.ptp-sync_is_outgrowing_rapidly_all_other_directories._Is_there_any_way_to_reset_.ptp-sync_.3F) instead of actually fixing the problem.